# make ChatHead View inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, ontouchlistener, android-windowmanager

I am trying to add **onTouchListener to imageButton** to move Like **chatHead** as we see in `facebook`.

> But when I add them to **LinearLayout or RelativeLayout** , their params doesn't have x,y attributes like WindowManager

But it is working in `WindowManger`. See

```
chatHead = new ImageView(this);
chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.face1);

params= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
params.x = 0;
params.y = 100;

//this code is for dragging the chat head
chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    private int initialX;
    private int initialY;
    private float initialTouchX;
    private float initialTouchY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            initialX = params.x;
            initialY = params.y;
            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            params.x = initialX
                + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
            params.y = initialY
                + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
```

Or is there a way to **Add Top margins to WindowManager** . So that `chatHead` Works below a `specified view`. I want to Add a button to the top of the screen. And the chatHead must not overlap it. But I can't find a way to add it under button.